# Mimic Google with 'Jquery delay' and 'fadeOut'

Tags: jquery, events, function

I have this piece of code:

```
$(input).keyup(function() {

    var searchTerms = getSearch();
          doSearch(searchTerms); 

});
```

The function `doSearch` gives me a list of results (search results). I would like to mimic Google by 'fading' out the results on keyup then set a timer or event .delay and then do the function which is providing the results, so:

1. keyup --> fade out 50%
2. wait a period of time
3. do function `doSearch(searchTerms);`

I know how to do the events but I cant seem to put them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery happens to have two things to solve this.

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

and

[jQuery.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/)

If you want to delay e.g. the trigger function you either need to queue it in the fx-queue or in a separate queue. Here is how that works:

```
$("#myElement").delay(2000).queue(function(){ 
  var searchTerms = getSearch();
  doSearch(searchTerms); 
  $(this).dequeue(); 
});
```

If you don’t want to use the default fx-queue, this is how to queue the function in your own queue:

```
$("#myElement").delay(2000, "myQueue").queue("myQueue", function(){ 
  var searchTerms = getSearch();
  doSearch(searchTerms); 
}).dequeue("myQueue");
```

Comment: This looks like an event..I have no problem doing events, its relating them to function I have a problem with. So `$(this).trigger("click");` How do I do that with `doSearch(searchTerms);`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `fadeTo`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ and JS' own `setTimeout` to do this. A little like:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function(){
   $('.stuffToFade').fadeTo('fast',0.5,function(){ //fade all '.stuffToFade' elements to 0.5 and execute the following callback
      setTimeout(function(){ //the following function will be executed after 500ms
         var searchTerms = getSearch();
         doSearch(searchTerms);
      }, 500); //this is where the delay is set
   });
});
```

Comment: Then we can't help you (dont know where) show a little more code, some errors, anything that seems to be the problem and we'll be glad to help you

Comment: @Joeri Minnekeer There is something wrong with the code I think, not with mine. I cant point out what it is becouse I didnt write the code above. So instead of thinking the prolem is on my side...You could have done some more thinking.

Comment: @Youss I missed an additional `);`, other than that it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MHreV/ - btw: this is not a place where you get copy/paste code for your projects, you should at least try to understand what people are telling you

Comment: If the problem wasn't on your side, you wouldn't have posted here right? So instead of personally insulting my intelligence, try to boost yours first

Answer (score 0):

function to a click handler:

```
$(this).click(function(){
   doSomeFunction(variable);
});
```

OR custom event:

```
$(this).doSearch(function(searchTerms){
    getyourSearchOn();
});
```